# how can I disable control alt delete

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In Ubuntu you can disable it in the shortcut menu http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/use-ctrl-alt-del-task-manager-ubuntu/ 
I have already tried editing the file located at

```
/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf
```

and commenting it all out (it does absolutely nothing).
how can I stop it doing something when I press control alt delete.
 i am using Freya 32 bit
and the output of `systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target` is command not found

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/763887/49899), `control-alt-delete.conf` is no longer used in Loki (which is based on Ubuntu Xenial).

They recommend:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
systemctl daemon-reload
```